# how to reformat, fix or repair a partition that was wrongly placed?

Tags: partitioning

It seems i somehow mixed up my partitions [image: partitions_pic] and set NVME01p6 as /home when it should of been NVME01p5, is that correct? I got an error saying im out of room and noticed only then. I dont have much on the partition and could always delete and reinstall but im not to sure if there would be an easier method or an application i can download that will edit those two partitions with out having to delete. again, im new and really know next to nothing other that what i learn from here. a few instructions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are using, but you can always change your mounts by editing the *file system table* (/etc/fstab)

Answer (score 1):

The partitions are completely up to you which one maps to which mount but, if your intention was to make NVME01p5 your /home, then that's correct.

It's a few steps to fix this (run all the commands as root or with sudo):

1. Ensure that you're the only one logged into the OS
2. Mount the new /home somewhere temporarily, you can do something like:

   1. `mkdir /mnt/new_home`
   2. `mount /dev/NVME01p5 /mnt/new_home`
3. Make sure that `/mnt/new_home` is empty (if there's a `lost+found` directory, that's fine)
4. Copy all the data from your old home to your new home using `rsync -a /home /mnt/new_home`
5. Unmount the new home:

   1. `umount /mnt/new_home`
   2. `rmdir /mnt/new_home`
6. Edit your `/etc/fstab` by finding the line that contains `/home` and replace the `/dev/NVME01p6` with `/dev/NVME01p5`
7. Reboot